# saving multiple tables in xlsx files

Tags: r

do we have any functionality or function which can paste multiple tables in single sheet of xlsx files.

lets say i have n number of tables and all tables have different size and format. now i want to save all the tables in xlsx file in one single sheet. with a specific space between them.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(fs)
library(writexl)

#l <- list(IRIS = iris, MTCARS = mtcars)
#write.xlsx(l, file = "writeXLSX2.xlsx")
#write.xlsx(l, file = "writeXLSXTable2.xlsx", asTable = TRUE)

My output is like the output of many tables 
t1 = mtcars

t2 = mtcars[,1:5]

t3= IRIS

t4 = IRIS[1:8,]
```

at last it should create a list of all the tables above and then paste in xlsx file with specific space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be the `openxlsx` package which allows you to write data starting at any row or column. To this end you have to set or compute the starting rows for each table taking account the number of rows of all previous written tables:

```r
library(openxlsx)

tbls <- list(
  t1 = mtcars,
  t2 = mtcars[,1:5],
  t3= iris,
  t4 = iris[1:8,]  
)
# Starting Row = number of rows of prev. table 
# + 2 (for the header and to add a empty row)
# + 1 for the first table

startRows <- c(0, cumsum(2 + sapply(tbls, nrow)[-length(tbls)])) + 1

fn <- tempfile(fileext = "xlsx")

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "tbls")
mapply(function(tbl, startRow) writeData(wb, "tbls", x = tbl, startRow = startRow), tbls, startRows)
#> t1 t2 t3 t4 
#>  0  0  0  0
saveWorkbook(wb, fn, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: its not saving file on my side, cant see the result

Comment: The issue is perhaps that I used a temporary file for the reprex, i.e. `fn <- tempfile(fileext = "xlsx")`. Have you tried with e.g. `fn <- "foo.xlsx"`? In that case the code should create a file `foo.xlsx` in your working directory.